# Unix copy for each line in file

Tags: unix, cp

I have a file, `file_copy`, which has:

```
>cat file_copy
file1
file2
file3
```

I want to copy `file1`, `file2`, `file3` from `/source` to `/dest`.  One way I know how to do this is to just do:

```
for line in `cat file_copy` ; do cp /source/$line /dest; done
```

But I know that there is a better way, probably using find/xargs and/or awk, etc. What is the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to iterate over lines in a file is [using `while`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while read line; do cp /source/"$line" /dest/; done < file_copy
```

And while the above is good enough for most cases, a more robust solution (although rarely needed) is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do cp /source/"$line" /dest/; done < file_copy
```

The `IFS=` prevents whitespace from being trimmed at the start and end of a line. `-r` prevents backslashes from being discarded.

---

Regarding your original command:

- There's a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).
- You [shouldn't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) because it's prone to errors when your lines contain whitespace. In practice, if you find yourself using `for` with anything else than looping over file names generated by the shell (e.g. `for f in *.csv`), you're probably doing something wrong.
- You should also quote your variables to prevent file names with spaces from being broken up into multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3):

To improve performance you might consider do this:

```
tar -cf -  'cat source.txt' | (cd $dest ; tar -xf -)
```

Compress files inside your source and extract them will do the job faster than loop!